# SF book about a town displaced in time by an accident at a local lab

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a book about a small town displaced in time or to an alternate universe, as told by a juvenile.  There's an experimental lab and something goes wrong and the lab and local town are transported elsewhere, where the natives' rules are almost Puritan-like, very strict.  The juvenile, I believe was a boy, whose uncle was the scientist who caused the town to shift.  The ending was that the uncle was going to try to shift them again.

Answer (score 10):

I'm almost certain you are referring to [Mysterium](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0071UJMCE) by Robert Charles Wilson.  I read it just a few months ago and it almost exactly matches your description.

Excerpt from a [Goodreads review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/652124456?book_show_action=true):

> A shard is found by an excavator. When subjected to radiation as it is studied, it transports the town of Two Rivers to an alternate reality / timeline where Christianity is not a major religion, instead Gnosticism holds sway. The town members of Two Rivers are subjected to the strict laws and rules of this different society with resultant severe punishments.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I've been looking for this book for over a year and now I have a title.